How can I recover from a psychological abuse from PhD advisor and move forward?
During my PhD, I encountered significant challenges that left me questioning my future in academia. My supervisor provided minimal guidance, and a colleague in my research group began treating me more like an assistant than an equal, often sidelining my contributions and using my work without my knowledge or proper acknowledgment. This led to increasing isolation, stress, and eventually, a break from my research.
As I approached the final stages of my PhD, the situation worsened. Despite needing support to complete my work, my PhD advisor refused to provide guidance or even meet with me, and when I requested a reference letter, it was denied without explanation. The university has been unsupportive, advising me to find a new advisor on my own.
Now, as I try to move forward, I’m struggling with the impact of these experiences. I’ve moved into a new role (as postdoc), but the damage to my confidence and motivation lingers. I’m unsure whether I should push through and finish my PhD or cut my losses and move on.
Given this background, what strategies can I use to rebuild my academic career, regain my confidence, and overcome the setbacks from my PhD experience?
Thank you for your advice and any help!

Have you been in touch with a personal counselor?

Hey, welcome to the site. There's a lot here, and I'm sorry you've been having a bad experience over the past few years. This question does have a lot in it, though, and in particular asks several questions at the same time. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance/417486#417486 from StackOverflow gives some details. If you're able to distill or break this up into individual questions via editing, that would help a lot in fitting with this site's Q&A format.

@user176372 The questioner is clearly in distress and needs help, perhaps immediate help. It therefore was certainly not a good idea to close this question.  I would strongly recommend to reopen it, despite all its flaws.  People in distress need support and advice, not corrections to their literary style.

@Michael_1812 this site and its format are particularly ill-equipped venues for providing aid to people in distress. I'd much rather we take the chance to direct people to better resources than leave questions open to gather discussion post answers which we have a hard time moderating.

@user176372 so please delete that question if you think that it is too broad or unnecessary for me to ask here for any advice.

@panegyricDoll you can't delete a question if it has an upvoted answer.

@user438383 so please take a look at the updated one if it meet your conditions, thank you.

@panegyricDoll Yes I think that's a much better and more focused question

The question should be reopened and the poster should be encouraged to provide more specific information about what led to the difficulties with the supervisor. It's hard to offer advice on moving forward unless we understand what caused the past problems. Many PhD students find themselves in similar situations and understanding and answering the OP's question could benefit many others.

Eggy, I would love to share more aspects of this story, but if they cannot re-open this question, I would rather to use another platform.

@user438383 Please reopen this question, thank you,


Except in extraordinary situations (like when the fate of your family is at stake), put you health (including your psychological health) first. Specifically, it would be better now to focus on moving forward, rather than filing formal complaints about your past experiences.

Sadly, it happens often that a busy advisor neglects their students.  My son had such an advisor, and chose to switch to a different school after fulfilling his Masters requirements. By word of mouth, he learned about a great professor from a different university, who was really caring about his students. So my son spoke with that professor, was urged to apply, got admitted, finished his PhD, got a job, and never had regrets about leaving the previous advisor.

Given your present condition, would it be of help for you to take a break? If yes, can you ask your doctor(s) to provide you with the necessary paperwork? Once again: put your health first. You will achieve a lot in your life if you stay healthy.



Thank you, @Michael_1812, for this advice! I've come to realize that my current procrastination on my PhD isn't a waste of time or resources after all. It's actually serving my well-being, and for the first time ever, I'm doing something that's genuinely beneficial for my mental health - beyond just seeking advice here or in via counsellor. Regarding my PhD, I've already informed my advisor that I’ve other priorities at the moment and won't be rushing to finish the project. I think it's also important to inform the Graduate School so they are aware of the situation and can stay up-to-date.

@panegyricDoll Whatever your choice happens to be, I wish you success in your endeavours. But first and foremost, try to stay healthy. Strong health and positive mood will open many doors for you. Good luck!!

I'm really sorry to hear about your tough PhD journey. There's nothing more stressful during a PhD than having a poor supervisor and a toxic work environment. I truly hope things start looking up for you soon.
In my previous department, several of my PhD colleagues have gone through similar challenges, and they described feeling just like you do. The good news is that almost all of them recovered and moved on after some time!
My advice would be to consider seeing a therapist who can offer tailored guidance to help you cope with these negative feelings. Some universities provide therapy services for students, so it might be worth reaching out to your PhD coordinator to see what resources are available.
Changing your supervisor could be crucial. Try reaching out to potential supervisors in your department—or even in other departments—for an informal meeting, maybe even over a coffee break. This could be a great way to discuss the possibility of supervision. It’s important to choose someone with good supervision skills, so talk to other PhD students about their experiences with different supervisors. You might need to adjust your research project slightly with a new supervisor, so finding someone who works in a related area could make the transition smoother.
You can also consider national or international mobility to another university for a period. In Europe, it's quite common for PhD students to spend a few months at another institution. This could give you the opportunity to work in a healthier environment and expand your academic network.
Hope this help, BEST OF LUCK 

+1 for the suggestion of therapy.  My journey was rough in similar ways, and I suspect I could have really benefitted from some therapy.  But, perversely, the situation left me feeling so drained of energy and time that I could not conceive of carving out the time to actually do it.
